# Dynamic Business Objects in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a c# application where I am reading individual columns of stored procedure results into output class objects. However if the number of columns in the stored procedure changes, i have to rewrite the data access layer code.

Is there any way where changing the number of columns in the output stored procedure doesn't make me change the code in the data access layer? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

There are ORM tools that can automatically generate data access layer code for you. In the case of .NET, there is the Entity Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to change the structure of the data returned and you rely on that structure it will always result in code changes whether your do your own mapping, use an ORM, or rely on a simple `DataTable` as a container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Presently I am reading the columns into sqldatareader through column names. Hence whenever the number of column changes, the codebase at the DAL fails. So you say, there's always gotta be a change in c# code whenever the number of columns in the sproc output varies?

Comment: I'm afraid so.  If you are using column `FirstName` taking it away is going to require changes to not only your DAL but to that code where the first name is used.  When you find that you need to use `LastName` where you are not already doing so I guess you will be writing code to use it somewhere and you will need to change your DAL to return the new data.

Comment: The only time you would not need to change the DAL code is when new columns are returned from your SP and you are not interested in them or when columns are dropped that you were not using anyway.  Use only what you need --- YAGNI :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that, Data-First model in EF may work in this scenario. Also was going through ExpandoObjects in c# 4.5. Maybe this can work too.